# Adding Email markup to an email sent via sendgrid. Is it possible?

Tags: sendgrid

I have asked sendgrid several times if this is possible and there support appears to have no idea.

I know I can not use the  tag in sendgrid that is fine so I am attempting to use the [microdata](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/formats/microdata)

I am using a dynamic template and sending the html over the api and then injecting it to the html. Has anyone successfull implemented this? I am currently stuck with the fact that they I have link tracking enabled and there clicktracking="off" apparenlty only works for  tags.

Answer (score 0):

I was missundertanding [how the test](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/) tool worked :(

I was pasting in the email content into here and then it was telling me my mark up was valid. If I pasted in my actual html before sending the email it told me the html was invalid

The clicktracking="off" appears not to have been the issue at all.